# jQuery Validate File Type On Change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery File Upload. That upload function is only allow image type. `.jpg, .gif, .png`

Assume I have 2 file, that's a.jpg & b.pdf. Now, I change the extension b.pdf to be b.jpg

a.jpg is original image.
b.jpg is not an original image.

My question, how can I validate that b.jpg is not an original image?

Here is my JS script :

```
$(function()
{
    $("#file").change(function()
    {
        var file = this.files[0];
        var imagefile = file.type;
        var match= ["image/jpeg","image/png","image/jpg"];
        var file_size = this.files[0].size;

        if(!((imagefile==match[0]) || (imagefile==match[1]) || (imagefile==match[2])))
        {
            alert("Invalid File");
        }
        else
        {
            var reader = new FileReader();  

            reader.onload = imageIsLoadeds;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }

        function imageIsLoadeds(e)
        {
            if(file_size>=1024000)
            {
                alert("File Size Error");
            }
            else
            {
                $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to validate the MIME Type of the content being uploaded.

First select the required MIME type (Reference: http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html).

Second you can use jQuery Validation Plugin to verify the MIME type of the uploaded content. (Reference: http://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method/)

Comment: Hi @planet260, How can I combine that Accept Method function into my current function? Please advise.

Comment: validate function will be called before submitting your form. For details please use this reference(http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) it has many options available on how you can change flows and show errors.